# levels in xcode spritekit, swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I have made some games in Xcode using spritkit(Swift); however, never with levels. I do not really understand how you make different levels in spritekit. It does not seem like a good idea to make different levels in different "GameScenes", or is it? I would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That really depends on your game ... You should be more specific ...

Comment: Lets take for example a maze game. Roll a ball through different patterns in every level @Whirlwind

Comment: Well, it depends on how you create a level. You can define walls coordinates, save them to disk, and read from a file whenever you need to load a new level. Or you can use [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) to create levels for your game. Or I guess, you could try to use SpriteKit's scene editor and save static content into .sks files.

Comment: Okay thanks! How do you mean to save the to disk and read from file. In practice how do you do it? @Whirlwind

Comment: You know, just ordinary data saving to a .plist file ... There are a lot of examples on this site already. Just search about data persistence and writing into files in Swift and you will find some more useful info about all this.

Comment: Aha perfect, thx. Really appreciate the help @Whirlwind

Comment: No problem :) Just note that questions like this are against the StackOverflow rules, and often end up being downvoted or closed. You should always be specific as much as you can. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And good luck with your game :)

Comment: Yes I know, unfortunately:( but thats a good tip. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 6):

I understand this is very late but I'd like to help future programmers. The way I was taught to add levels in a way similar to how Angry Birds has its levels. What you do is create a new .sks file by going in Xcode to

> File => New => File...

When the popup appears select SpriteKit Scene. Save its name to whatever you feel like. At this time, take a break to make your level alone in the new SpriteKit Scene. Here's an example for a game similar to Angry Birds:

[image: Example]

[Required] Now, to be precise in where you want the level to be, go to your GameScene.sks file and add a new node to the place you want your level to be. In the Attributes inspector, name the node to levelNode.

[image]

Now, go to your GameScene.swift file. Go to the top of the file and add

```
var levelNode:SKNode!
```

Then navigate to your didMoveToView function and add the following code to the beginning of it:

```
levelNode = self.childNodeWithName("levelNode")
```

After the that line of code, add this:

```
let resourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("WhateverYouNamedYourLevel", ofType: "sks")
let newLevel = SKReferenceNode (URL: NSURL (fileURLWithPath: resourcePath!))
    levelNode.addChild(newLevel)
```

Good Job! You have just created your first level!
Hope this helped, feel free to leave an upvote! :p